# Can we detect if our chrome extension has crashed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have built a chrome extension and it has crashed a couple of times on a single machine.  We want to know if it has crashed on any other machines once we deploy it out to the whole wide world.  Is there any api that we let us detect the crash and report it back to us?  Or if the user has crash logging enabled for chrome will Google pass on the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome://crashes/` is the place where all information like crash Id are logged. There is no API till date for detection of Chrome Crashes.